# Group by key words found in one column, then show summary statistics for another column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a quick way to group records by a key word/string found in one column, and display summary statistics (.describe(), .mean(), etc.) for another column.

Below is a snippet of the code I was trying. I'm trying to avoid splitting/sub setting into a bunch of different dataframes.

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
PROMOTED_PRODUCT__CREATIVE              ROAS
0   Simple Green 1 Gal. Concentrated    0.027573
1   Simple Green 1 Gal. Concentrated    0.082969
2   Simple Green 1 Gal. Concentrated    0.056278
3   Simple Green 1 Gal. Concentrated    0.037286
4   Simple Green 1 Gal. Concentrated    0.355843


df_pi['PROMOTED_PRODUCT__CREATIVE'].str.contains('1 gal', re.IGNORECASE).groupby(df_pi['PROMOTED_PRODUCT__CREATIVE'])['ROAS'].mean()
```

When I run the following code, it results in a key error:

```
KeyError: 'Column not found: ROAS'
```

I understand that it's because it's not a dataframe/there are no column headers. Should I do this in steps instead of a single line?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a mask and filter the dataframe by this mask before doing `.groupby`:

```py
mask = df["PROMOTED_PRODUCT__CREATIVE"].str.contains(
    "1 gal", flags=re.IGNORECASE
)

x = df[mask].groupby("PROMOTED_PRODUCT__CREATIVE")["ROAS"].mean()

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
PROMOTED_PRODUCT__CREATIVE
Simple Green 1 Gal. Concentrated    0.11199
Name: ROAS, dtype: float64
```